# Wrong index used in Postrgres

Tags: postgresql

I have Postrgres 9.3 running on a Linux machine with 32GB RAM. I have a fairly large database (some tables with approx. 1 mil. records) and I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT c.ext_content_id AS type_1_id,
"substring"(c.ext_content_id::text, 1, 13) AS type_1_album_id,
cm1.value AS type_1_artist,
cm2.value AS type_1_title,
cm4.value AS type_1_duration,
pm1.value AS type_1_icpn,
cm3.value AS type_1_isrc,
c.provider AS type_1_provider,
to_number(cm5.value::text, '999999'::text) AS type_2_set_number,
to_number(cm6.value::text, '999999'::text) AS type_2_track_number,
cm7.value AS type_6_availability_ppd,
cm12.value AS type_6_availability_sub,
cm9.value AS type_1_language,
cm11.value AS type_1_label_reporting_id,
cm13.value AS type_1_parent_isrc
FROM content c
LEFT JOIN content_metadata cm1 ON c.content_id = cm1.content_id AND cm1.name::text = 'track_artist'::text
LEFT JOIN content_metadata cm2 ON c.content_id = cm2.content_id AND cm2.name::text = 'track_title'::text
LEFT JOIN content_metadata cm3 ON c.content_id = cm3.content_id AND cm3.name::text = 'track_isrc'::text
LEFT JOIN content_metadata cm4 ON c.content_id = cm4.content_id AND cm4.name::text = 'track_duration'::text
LEFT JOIN content_metadata cm5 ON c.content_id = cm5.content_id AND cm5.name::text = 'set_number'::text
LEFT JOIN content_metadata cm6 ON c.content_id = cm6.content_id AND cm6.name::text = 'track_number'::text
LEFT JOIN content_metadata cm7 ON c.content_id = cm7.content_id AND cm7.name::text = 'unlimited'::text
LEFT JOIN content_metadata cm9 ON c.content_id = cm9.content_id AND cm9.name::text = 'language'::text
LEFT JOIN content_metadata cm10 ON c.content_id = cm10.content_id AND cm10.name::text = 'import_date'::text
LEFT JOIN content_metadata cm11 ON c.content_id = cm11.content_id AND cm11.name::text = 'label_reporting_id'::text
LEFT JOIN content_metadata cm12 ON c.content_id = cm12.content_id AND cm12.name::text = 'subscription'::text
LEFT JOIN content_metadata cm13 ON c.content_id = cm13.content_id AND cm13.name::text = 'parent_isrc'::text,
product p
LEFT JOIN product_metadata pm4 ON p.product_id = pm4.product_id AND pm4.name::text = 'product_title'::text
LEFT JOIN product_metadata pm1 ON p.product_id = pm1.product_id AND pm1.name::text = 'upc'::text
WHERE p.ext_product_id::text = substr(c.ext_content_id::text, 1, 13)
) view
WHERE type_1_id='1-111-1027897-01-001';
```

Below are the definitions of the tables involved.

Content:

```
                  Table "public.content"
     Column      |            Type             | Modifiers
-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 content_id      | bigint                      | not null
 status          | character varying(3)        | not null
 display_name    | character varying(1024)     | not null
 ext_content_id  | character varying(64)       | not null
 provider        | character varying(128)      | not null
 last_updated_by | character varying(30)       | not null
 last_updated_on | timestamp without time zone | not null
 created_by      | character varying(30)       | not null
 created_on      | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "content_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (content_id)
    "ak_key_2_content" UNIQUE, btree (ext_content_id, provider)
    "index_content_01" UNIQUE, btree (ext_content_id)
    "pk_content" UNIQUE, btree (content_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_content_01" FOREIGN KEY (provider) REFERENCES provider(ext_provider_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "content_metadata" CONSTRAINT "fk_content_metadata_01" FOREIGN KEY (content_id) REFERENCES content(content_id)
    TABLE "packaged" CONSTRAINT "fk_packaged_reference_content" FOREIGN KEY (content_id) REFERENCES content(content_id)
    TABLE "product_content" CONSTRAINT "fk_product_content_01" FOREIGN KEY (content_id) REFERENCES content(content_id)
Triggers:
    td_content BEFORE DELETE ON content FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_fct_td_content()
    ti_content BEFORE INSERT ON content FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_fct_ti_content()
    tu_content BEFORE UPDATE ON content FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_fct_tu_content()
    tu_content_tree BEFORE UPDATE ON content FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_fct_tu_content_tree()
```

Product:

```
              Table "public.product"
     Column      |            Type             | Modifiers
-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 product_id      | bigint                      | not null
 status          | character varying(3)        | not null
 display_name    | character varying(1024)     | not null
 ext_product_id  | character varying(64)       | not null
 last_updated_by | character varying(30)       | not null
 last_updated_on | timestamp without time zone | not null
 created_by      | character varying(30)       | not null
 created_on      | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "product_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (product_id)
    "ak_key_2_product" UNIQUE, btree (ext_product_id)
    "pk_product" UNIQUE, btree (product_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "contract_product" CONSTRAINT "fk_contract_product_02" FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product(product_id)
    TABLE "offer_product" CONSTRAINT "fk_offer_product_01" FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product(product_id)
    TABLE "product_metadata" CONSTRAINT "fk_product__reference_product" FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product(product_id)
    TABLE "product_content" CONSTRAINT "fk_product_content_02" FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product(product_id)
Triggers:
    td_product BEFORE DELETE ON product FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_fct_td_product()
    ti_product BEFORE INSERT ON product FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_fct_ti_product()
    tu_product BEFORE UPDATE ON product FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_fct_tu_product()
    tu_product_tree BEFORE UPDATE ON product FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_fct_tu_product_tree()
```

Product_metadata:

```
          Table "public.product_metadata"
     Column      |            Type             | Modifiers
-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 product_id      | bigint                      | not null
 name            | character varying(64)       | not null
 distributor_id  | bigint                      |
 value           | character varying(4000)     |
 created_on      | timestamp without time zone | not null
 created_by      | character varying(30)       | not null
 last_updated_on | timestamp without time zone | not null
 last_updated_by | character varying(30)       | not null
Indexes:
    "idx_product_metadata_03" btree (name, value)
    "index_product_metadata_02" btree (product_id, name)
    "index_product_metadata_cid" btree (product_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_product__reference_product" FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product(product_id)
    "fk_product_metadata_02" FOREIGN KEY (distributor_id) REFERENCES operator(operator_id)
Triggers:
    td_product_metadata BEFORE DELETE ON product_metadata FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_fct_td_product_metadata()
    ti_product_metadata BEFORE INSERT ON product_metadata FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_fct_ti_product_metadata()
    tu_product_metadata BEFORE UPDATE ON product_metadata FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_fct_tu_product_metadata()
```

Content_metadata:

```
          Table "public.content_metadata"
     Column      |            Type             | Modifiers
-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 content_id      | bigint                      | not null
 name            | character varying(64)       | not null
 distributor_id  | bigint                      |
 value           | character varying(4000)     |
 last_updated_by | character varying(30)       | not null
 last_updated_on | timestamp without time zone | not null
 created_by      | character varying(30)       | not null
 created_on      | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "idx_content_metadata_03" btree (name, value)
    "idx_content_metadata_04" btree (content_id, name, value)
    "index_content_metadata_02" btree (content_id, name)
    "index_content_metadata_cid" btree (content_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_content_metadata_01" FOREIGN KEY (content_id) REFERENCES content(content_id)
    "fk_content_metadata_02" FOREIGN KEY (distributor_id) REFERENCES operator(operator_id)
Triggers:
    td_content_metadata BEFORE DELETE ON content_metadata FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_fct_td_content_metadata()
    ti_content_metadata BEFORE INSERT ON content_metadata FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_fct_ti_content_metadata()
    tu_content_metadata BEFORE UPDATE ON content_metadata FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_fct_tu_content_metadata()
```

The query as it is takes approx. 35 seconds, which is very bad. If I take out the line:

```
LEFT JOIN product_metadata pm4 ON p.product_id = pm4.product_id AND pm4.name::text = 'product_title'::text
```

then the time is under 1 second.

Here you can see the plan for the query (as it is here, i.e. when it takes a lot of time): http://explain.depesz.com/s/K9s

As far as I can see, the wrong index is used. In the lines

```
"->  Bitmap Heap Scan on product_metadata pm4  (cost=6014.11..257694.54 rows=579474 width=8) (actual time=282.364..13005.344 rows=557834 loops=1)"
    "Recheck Cond: ((name)::text = 'product_title'::text)"
    "Buffers: shared read=175851"
    "->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_product_metadata_03  (cost=0.00..5869.24 rows=579474 width=0) (actual time=222.724..222.724 rows=557834 loops=1)"
        "Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'product_title'::text)"
        "Buffers: shared read=3953"
```

it can be seen that it uses idx_product_metadata_03 which is on (name, value). Shouldn't it use index_product_metadata_02 which is on (product_id, name)?

Or is there another reason why this query is so slow?

If you need any other information, let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have multiple indexes for either the same column or the same leading columns?

Comment: Yeah, that's a mistake, only noticed it now. But should this have something to do with the problem I'm having?

Comment: Also, why no ANSI-style join to `product`?

Comment: What do you mean by that, sorry? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Colin is referring to the fact that you used explicit `JOIN`s for all tables except `product` which is just listed in the from part and then an implicit join is done in the `where` clause. I'm actually surprised that it works at all.

Comment: So what should the query look like in this case?

Comment: Mmm, EAV schema. You're never going to see wonderful performance here. Ever looked at `hstore`, `json` etc?

Comment: Can you test if adding indexes on `content_metadata (name, content_id, value)` and on `product_metadata (name, product_id, value)` a) are used and b) if it improves the efficiency of the query?

Comment: I would try rewriting the query by using an explicit `JOIN product p` and by removing the unnecessary derived table (`view`).

Comment: The `DISTINCT` also looks redundant. What happens if you remove it, do you really get duplicate rows in the result?

Answer (score 1):

After posting the question to pgsql-performance, one suggestion I got there was to increase `join_collapse_limit` and `from_collapse_limit`. I did that (increased both to 40) and the query now takes less than a second. Don't know yet though what implications this will have on the long run. But for now it's all good.

Thanks everybody!

Comment: The implication is that you are now probably using the genetic query optimizer which means that it no longer does an exhaustive search for plans with more than `geqo_threshold` "FROM items" (which defaults to 12). See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-GEQO-THRESHOLD It's probably a good thing in your situation for the optimizer not to spend too much time searching for a plan. But it may result in different/worse plans for other things that were working fine.

Comment: Like @CraigRinger suggests, you should probably look into something like `hstore` for your EAV data model.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an index that can be used to match the text field.  Using bitmap indexes to combine the two queries on the product-metadata table is a common optimization technique to replace a full table scan.

It does appear you have over-normalized you table structure. You are likely to their are performance impacts to large metatdata tables.  You should consider moving the metadata into their related tables (with appropriate indexes) or splitting columns into single tables.

Comment: But the JOIN is on p.product_id = pm4.product_id AND pm4.name::text = 'product_title'::text so shouldn't index_product_metadata_02 which is on (product_id, name) be used in this case?

Comment: @StelianIancu The where clause is important here.  It adds an implicit join on part of the ext_product_id column, and then adding the metadata.  Index statistics may not be trusted, or may suggest a table scan is required.  You may get better results by adding a function based index.